# Mongoose array filtering and returning filtered array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My document have field `roomname` and field `users` which is an array:

```
['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4' ,'name5' ,'name6' ,'name7']
```

How can I get filtered array of users from 'name2' to 'name5'?
I get from 'name1' to 'name7' array by coding :

```js
roommodel.find({roomname:'room1'},'users').then(res=>{
  console.log(res)
})
```

When there is less number of users like this one then there is a way:

```js
let filteredusers=res.slice(1,4).map(i=>return i)
```

If there is huge amount of arrays it may slowdown server. I want to know if there is a direct method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Aggregation` framework. Note that you will have to pass the input of all the indexes of **users** array that you want to be returned.

- `$match` to filter relevant document
- `$map` to iterate over the input array of **indexes**
- `$arrayElemAt` to return the element from **users** array by the index

```
roommodel.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "roomname": "room1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "users": {
        "$map": {
          "input": [
            2,
            3,
            4
          ],
          "in": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$users",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y6IV-ei1jRg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it **$nin** Condition in Mongodb Query Like this,

```
roommodel.find({
    roomname:'room1', 
    username: { $nin: [ 'name1', 'name7' ] }},'users')
.then(res=>{
   console.log(res)
})
```